# POST request using mysql2 with nextjs13 gives HTTP 500

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, next.js13

I have a form that takes in multiple inputs and I am trying to send that data to MySQL database. The database connection is established as I can do GET part successfully, but the POST request part does not work. Weirdly enough, I do not get errors in the browser console or my terminal when i submit the form. But when I navigate to `api/application` it gives HTTP 500. For context, i am using **nextjs13, MySQL workbench and mysql2 npm package**.

I expect that once the user clicks on Save, the data should get added to application table and I should see a 'Success' message. But nothing happens, it doesn't add at all.
Here is my `application` table in MySQL workbench.

```
CREATE TABLE application (
  App_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  Status VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "Pending",
  c_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
  Sex CHAR,
  child_age INT,
  p_id VARCHAR(20),
  g_disorder ENUM('Yes', 'No') NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES child(Child_id), # Foreign keys 
  FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES parents(Parent_id) # Foreign keys
);
ALTER TABLE application AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

This is where i have created the POST request handler `app/api/application/route.js`:

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";  // this the package i have installed
import { query } from "../../lib/db";  // connection part, has .createConnection() and .execute() methods defined
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request) {
    let message;
    const sex = request.body.Sex;
    const childAge = request.body.child_age;
    const parentID = request.body.p_id;
    const geneticDisorder = request.body.g_disorder;
    const addApplicationData = await query({
        query: "INSERT INTO application(Sex, child_age, p_id, g_disorder) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
        values: [sex, childAge, parentID, geneticDisorder],
    });

    // if insertion was a success, it generates an id
    if (addApplicationData.insertId) {
        message = "success"
    } else {
        message = "error"
    }

    let applicationData = {
        App_id: addApplicationData.insertId,
        Sex: sex,
        child_age: childAge,
        p_id: parentID,
        g_disorder: geneticDisorder
    };

    return NextResponse.json({ response: { message: message, applicationData: applicationData } });
}
```

This is my client side form: `app/application/page.js`:

```
"use client"

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';


const Application = () => {
  const parentIDToAddRef = useRef();
  const sexOfChildToAddRef = useRef();
  const ageOfChildToAddRef = useRef();
  const genDisorderToAddRef = useRef();

  const [created, setCreated] = useState(false);
  async function addData () {
      const sex = sexOfChildToAddRef.current.value.trim();
      const childAge = ageOfChildToAddRef.current.value.trim();
      const parentID = parentIDToAddRef.current.value.trim();
      const geneticDisorder = genDisorderToAddRef.current.value.trim();

      const postData = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          Sex: sex,
          child_age: parseInt(childAge, 10),  // conv to int because MySQL schema has child_age INT
          p_id: parentID, 
          g_disorder: geneticDisorder,
        }),
      };
      if (parentID.length !== 14) {
        return;
      }
      const res = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/application`,
      postData
      );
      const response = await res.json();
      console.log(response);
      if (response.response.message !== "success") return;
      setCreated(true);
    }
    
  return (
    <main>
        <form onSubmit={addData}>
            <div>
                <h1>Fill your Application</h1>
                <div>
                    {/* Id of parents */}
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="p_id">Enter your ID</label>
                        <p></p>
                        <input 
                        type="text"
                        ref={parentIDToAddRef}
                        placeholder="4222 2224 4222"
                        required
                        />
                    </div>
                    {/* Sex of the child input */}
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="Sex">Sex of the child</label>
                        <p></p>
                        <input 
                        type="text"
                        ref={sexOfChildToAddRef}
                        placeholder="M / F" 
                        required
                        />
                    </div>
                    {/* Age of child input */}
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="child_age">Age of the child</label>
                        <p></p>
                        <input
                        type="number"
                        ref={ageOfChildToAddRef}
                        placeholder="Enter age of the child"
                        required
                        />
                    </div>
                    {/* Gen disorder radio */}
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="g_disorder">Are you okay if the child has a genetic disorder?</label>
                        <p></p>
                        <input 
                        id="yes"
                        type="radio"
                        ref={genDisorderToAddRef}
                        value="Yes"
                        required
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="yes">Yes</label>
                        <p></p>
                        <input  
                        id="no"
                        type="radio"
                        ref={genDisorderToAddRef}
                        value="No"
                        required
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="no">No</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input
                value="Save"
                type="button"
              />
            </div>
        </form>
        {created && <div>Success!</div>}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Application;
```

Please help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the new app folder in use, your route handler file needs to be called `route.js|ts`. Therefore, instead of using `api/application`, your file structure should be `api/application/route.js|ts`. You can read more about route handling in next js [route handlers section](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)